# C++ Codebase does not compile after upgrade to Linux Mint 19, unable to resolve stl and boost functions

Tags: linux-mint, c++

Recently, I have been using Mint 19.

We have a C++ codebase which I am compiling using cmake, make and therefore g++ (version 7.4) and gcc (v 7.4).

Under Mint 18, the whole project compiles.
Now, under Mint 19, most files are translated as usual but some are not.

It seems to me that some includes are not resolved, for example,

```
error: ‘fillPoly’ is not a member of ‘cv’
error: ‘boost::optional’ has not been declared
```

I have already tried to compile using  `-std=gnu++0x`.
I have installed build-essentials, `libopencv-dev`.

Normally, I would suggest that there are missing header files but the project compiles under Mint 18.

I am able to resolve some of these error messages by including e.g. boost optional.

My question is: what is causing this behavior? Why does the codebase compiles using an older tool chain?

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. If you don't get a good response here you might want to try posting in the section specifically for programming questions: https://stackoverflow.com/